# jQuery: select element from parsed html snippet

Tags: javascript

Inside a class method I parse a html snippet like this:

```
    this.editCtrl = $('<input type="radio" name="society" value="existing"><select class="society"></select></input><input type="radio" name="society" value="existing"><input type="text"></input></input>');
```

I can add this snippet to my DOM and everything works fine, but before doing so I would like to fill the drop down. I tried to get it like this:

```
    var dropdown = this.editCtrl.find('select.society');
```

and like this:

```
    var dropdown = $('select.society', this.editCtrl);
```

The length of the result set is zero in both cases. What's the correct way to get a certain element from such an html snippet?

Comment: FYI it should be `<input />`, Not `<input>stuff</input>`. input elements are strictly empty: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter` in this case:

```
$('<input type="radio" name="society" value="existing"><select class="society"></select></input><input type="radio" name="society" value="existing"><input type="text"></input></input>').filter(function() {
    return $(this).is('select.society')
})
```

Reason being that if you were to use `find` you would need to from the parent element of your `<select>`, otherwise you are directly searching the elements and not from above them.